# ASP print function not working

Tags: asp.net

I am using code from an article top print a gridview on an ASP.Net webpage. It works fine when I debug it on my computer, however, when I deploy it the popup gives the following error:
**Description:** An error occurred during the compilation of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific error details and modify your source code appropriately.

**Compiler Error Message:** CS0103: The name 'PrintHelper' does not exist in the current context
Heres the Code:
On Main site with grid:

```
    protected void CmdPrint_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    Session["ctrl"] = GridView1;
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "onclick", "<script language=javascript>window.open('Print.aspx','PrintMe','height=300px,width=300px,scrollbars=1');</script>");
}
```

This causes a page to popup with the grid, then opens the print dialog:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Control ctrl = (Control)Session["ctrl"];
    PrintHelper.PrintWebControl(ctrl);
}
```

PrintHelper is static. Why would it not be recognizing it on live, but in debug it works fine?
The site is under the Default Web Site, but in its own app pool.

Comment: And where is a code of print helper? Do you include its namespace?

Comment: What's the project type: `web site` or `web application`?  Also, when testing are you deploying to a local area or simply hitting run?

Comment: Stupid question, but have to ask, are you sure the PrintHelper.cs and all supporting code files are deployed on the live server?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I believe printhelper will be called on the server, not the client.  Which is why you can use it while debugging, because your machine is both the client and the server.

Comment: I am simply hitting run. and the print page is deployed to the server.

Answer (score 0):

This link will help you

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/743070/the-name-xxx-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context

So, try to do static class....